# WordPress htaccess - restricted access to files (with exception)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, exception

I try to protect my files from not logged in users in 3 subfolders of wp-content/uploads, but i have to make an exception to the files with filename started with "*partner-*" from the folder1.

So in the case of folder1 i would handle the exception:

- folder1/partner-filename.jpg
- folder1/partner-filename2.jpg
- folder1/partner-filename3.jpg
  ...

Could anyone help me how can i define an exception like this **in htacces**?

To protect my 3 folders from not logged in users i already use this:

(UPDATED)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder2 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder3 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.wordpress_logged_in.$ [NC]
RewriteRule . – [R=403,L]
```

Comment: What you currently have, should not even do the job properly yet … You have all those conditions joined with OR, so this would get you a 403 on _any_ requested URL, if the cookie value was not found, regardless of whether it contained any of those three folder names or not.

Comment: It makes rather little sense to do such basic path checking using RewriteConds to begin with IMHO, that part should be handled by the RewriteRule, with a pattern with alternation, like `^(folder1|folder2|folder3)/`

Comment: Thanks @CBroe! I fixed the unnecessary OR operator. Could you help me how you propose to write the RewriteRule without any RewriteCondition? (It's not clear for me)

Comment: That does not fix the issue. Now the third and fourth condition are bound together by an implicit AND, and since that binds stronger than OR, you would still deny access to anyone requesting /folder1 or /folder2, regardless of whether or not they have this cookie set.

Comment: And the check you are attempting on the cookie value there, is not sufficient either. First of all, the mere existence of a cookie with a name starting with `wordpress_logged_in` does _not_ mean you actually have a logged-in user - _anyone_ could send a cookie with such a name. And HTTP_COOKIE contains _all_ cookies, in an order that is not really predictable - so as soon as more than one cookie gets used on that site, you can not expect `wordpress_logged_in` to be at the beginning of that value either.